# VBA Script to Fill Blank Cells Within an Excel Column with the Average of Nonblank Cells within that Same Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have no experience with VBA and would love some help. As the title indicates, I'm looking for a script that fills a certain number of blank cells within column G with the average of all nonblank cells within that same range (e.g. fill all blank cells in G16:G59 with the average of all nonblank cells within G16:G59).

To make things more complicated, I'd need to vary the range somewhat dynamically as I wouldn't be sure as to how many rows I'd need to apply this script to and a work colleague who would be using this script might not have any experience with VBA either... The easiest solution I can think of is to have another cell contain the name of the last row in the range, or something like this: "Fill all blank cells in G16:Gx with the average of all nonblank cells within G16:Gx, where x = the row name listed in cell G12". Within G12 I'd have a text that states the last row to define the range, e.g. cell G12 contains the text "G80", which makes the range within the script to read G16:G80.

I know I'm asking for a lot, so if you can even just provide guidance on the first bit, I'd be very grateful! Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Is it possible that the last cell in column G could be blank?  If so, is there another column that could be used to determine the last row of the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can all remember what it was like when we first started out with VBA coding – which is why I’m helping you here.  Normally, you’d be lucky to get any assistance with your question without providing at least some code & a description where it wasn’t doing what you wanted.  Using the `Record Macro` button is always a good place to start.

Assumptions made here are that the data is on “Sheet1” in your file, and that there is a value in the last cell in Column G in the range you’re interested in.  If that isn’t the case, let me know and I’ll show an alternative method to find the last row.

I’ve added descriptions about what (most) code does in each case to help you understand what’s going on.  Let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit     '<~~ get in the habit of putting this at the top of your code
Sub FillInBlanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet '<~~ declare all variables
Dim LastRow As Long '<~~ use Long not Integer
Dim cel As Range    '<~~ use intuitive variable names
Dim avg As Double   '<~~ Double used here if you want decimal places in the average

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")   '<~~ be explicit with sheet references

'Best practice to determine last used row in column
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row   '<~~ finds the last used row in column G

'Calculate the average & assign it to the variable "avg"
avg = Application.Average(ws.Range("G16:G" & LastRow))

'Loop through each cell in the defined range - one at a time
For Each cel In ws.Range("G16:G" & LastRow)
    If cel = "" Then  '<~~ = If the cell is blank, then...
        cel = avg     '<~~ ...put the average value (avg) in the cell
        cel.Font.Color = RGB(51, 102, 0) '<~~ change color to suit
    End If
Next cel      '<~~ go to the next cell in the range

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi kevin9999, thank you so much for the very descriptive and detailed response. This solution works perfectly! One last question, how would I go about changing the font color of cells that have the "avg" variable applied? I've been playing around with adding ".ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6" with the "Application.Average" formula, but am struggling to make it work

Comment: A dark green is fine, but really I'm more interested in understanding the syntax I'd use to get this to work. Thank you again!

Comment: Done! Please note the addition of the code line `cel.Font.Color = RGB(51,102,0)`.  You can tweak the RGB color to get the exact shade you're after.